# Keras 2.2.4 How to replicate merge( ) from Keras 1.x.x

Tags: python, tensorflow, merge, keras, deprecated

I am trying to convert Keras 1.x.x code into 2.2.x, with TensorFlow backend.

I have the below in Keras 1.x.x which takes the following inputs:

- `org_image` An image of 256x256 on 3 RGB color channels `shape=(256,256,3)`
- `mask` A mask of 256x256 on 1 B/W color channel `shape=(256,256,1)`

I wish to combine the image with the mask to get a new cropped image where the mask area is missing. To do so, I first take the inverse of `mask` using `1 - mask`, where `1` is a tensor of ones. Then I element-wise multiply `org_image * (1 - mask)` to get the newly cropped image. The code looks like below in Keras 1.x.x

```py
from keras.layers import Input, merge

input_shape = (256,256,3)

org_img = Input(shape=input_shape)
mask = Input(shape=(input_shape[0], input_shape[1], 1))
input_img = merge([org_img, mask],
                   mode=lambda x: x[0] * (1 - x[1]),
                   output_shape=input_shape)
```

In Keras 2.2.x a breaking change was introduced that replaced the `merge()` function with `Add()`, `Subtract()`, `Multiply()` ...etc. The previous `merge()` had the convinence of `mode=lambda x: x[0] * (1 - x[1])` which is equal to `mode=lambda [org_img, mask]: org_img * (1 - mask)`.

How can I replicate the `1 - mask` in Keras 2.2.x? Do I need to import in `tf.backend.ones`?

Or perhaps I need to `tf.enable_eager_execution()`?

I'm pretty new to this so I know a lot is going over my head. I'd really appreciate it if someone could clarify where my misconception is, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use `Lambda` layers for custom functions or lambda expressions:

```
input_img = Lambda(lambda x: x[0] * (1 - x[1]), output_shape=input_shape)([org_img, mask])
```

Where `output_shape` is optional if you're using tensorflow as backend.

Other useful layers:

- `Concatenate(axis=...)(list_of_inputs)`
- `Add()(list_of_inputs)`
- `Multiply()(list_of_inputs)`